# Can't seem to make display:flex work, so that the 3 divs are the same height

Tags: widget

I need to make sure that my 3 footer widgets are the same height, even if the site user decides to put more content in one of the widgets, so that they adjust in height. I understand using display: flex is the best solution. I can't seem to make it work.

My html:

```
<div class="footer-widgets"><div class="wrap"><div class="footer-widgets-1 widget-area"><section id="testimonial_footer-3" class="widget widget_testimonial_footer"><div class="widget-wrap"><div id="testimonial_widget"><h4 class="widget-title widgettitle">Testimonial</h4><p class="myclass">Loved being a student at derby skill build. They really helped me grow as a</p><div id='tinyname'> </p> - Louise findlay, former student </div>  </div></section>
</div><div class="footer-widgets-2 widget-area"><section id="blog_widget-2" class="widget widget_blog_widget"><div class="widget-wrap"><h4 class="widget-title widgettitle">Blog</h4>
<ul class="realty_widget">

       <div class="titleblogcolor"> <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?blog_posts=this-is-a-blog-by-a-student" title="this is a blog by a student">

this is a blog by a student</a></a> </div>

   Find out more about this in our blog. We have lots going on here at Derby Skill Build</ul></div></section>
</div><div class="footer-widgets-3 widget-area"><section id="black-studio-tinymce-2" class="widget widget_black_studio_tinymce"><div class="widget-wrap"><h4 class="widget-title widgettitle">Associated with:</h4>
<div class="textwidget"><p><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/council.png"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-244" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/council.png" alt="council" width="80" height="43" /></a> <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/edexcel.png"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-245" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/edexcel.png" alt="edexcel" width="80" height="15" /></a>  <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/ofsted.png"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-247" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/ofsted.png" alt="ofsted" width="80" height="69" /></a> <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/woodhead.png"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-248" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/woodhead.png" alt="woodhead" width="80" height="29" /></a> <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/ascentis.png"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-249" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/ascentis.png" alt="ascentis" width="80" height="49" /></a> <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/beauty2.png"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-250" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/beauty2.png" alt="beauty" width="80" height="35" /></a> <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/connexions.png"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-251" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/connexions.png" alt="connexions" width="100" height="23" /></a></p>
</div></div></section>
</div></div></div>
```

**I have tried the following in my style.css:**

```
.footer-widgets { display: flex; }

.footer-widgets .wrap (display: flex; }
```

neither seem to work.  I need to put `display: flex' for the parent div of these 3 widgets I understand. Any ideas please?

I am using the genesis framework.

Comment: you should organize your source code a bit. you would see, you dont close your tags correctly. might be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The items you want automatically adjusted (flex items) need to be contained in a parent flexbox.

So, you need to do something like this and apply it to your code:

```
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-item {
  flex: 1; /* you need to use the "flex" property on the items you want in the flexbox, not the "display" property */
}
```

It's hard to see what you want adjusted based on your code. All of the widgets will need to have the same child-to-parent relation with the .flexbox container. So, if you give each widget a class of .footer-widget, then you can use .flexbox > .footer-widget to target each flex-item.

Hope that helps!